# SignalR polling app on 200 ipads in a conference room. Bandwidth bottleneck when voting?

Tags: signalr, wireless, bandwidth

My app pops a polling question up on your iPad.  You vote.  And you see results.

Goal is to stick 200 people in an auditorium, give them iPads and go to town.  I have the iPads and have tried this.  Works great on a hard internet line out of the facility with about 8mb up.  When I go to two load balanced cradle point 4G LTE's voting grinds to a halt.

Now the obvious answer is your bandwidth is lower.  And it is.  Only showing 2-3MB up.  My thought is, though, that should be enough.  SignalR and WebAPI (which I use to write the actual votes to SQL) shouldn't be throwing around tons of data to register a simple multiple choice vote.

I used fiddler and watched one vote.  About 1K of data transferred, most in the header.  So 200 votes should be about 200K.  How am I pressing the limits of 2-3MB up here?  As soon as we get off wireless and go back to the hard line, all is well again.

Is this purely the drop in bandwidth causing the bog down, or is there something else inherent in wireless vs hard wire that also may slow things down.

Note, no dhcp involved.  IP's are pre set (reserved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from bandwidth there are other potential issues with your lte setup. The main one being the NAT on the routers. I know nothing about those routers you're using, but they may not be designed to deal with lot's of open connections. There will be a limit to the amount of connections they can handle both in terms of processing power as well as in terms of memory. On top of that you should add the increased latency introduced by the LTE connection, which makes everything even slower. I'm assuming you're using at least 2 connections per iPad (one for polling, one for vote submission). This means the router has to deal with 400 concurrent connections. A simple script on a laptop which starts 500 downloads will show you if it can take that kind of load.

Potentially there is also the NAT at your LTE provider which could cause issues. I've seen strange things at telcos, dropping your polling connection because they feel it's open to long could be one of them. But that wouldn't be the first place I'd look.

The location might matter as well, you measured 2MBs of bandwidth over LTE, but did you measure that again after those 200 people each carrying a smartphone walked into the room? The local celltower might just be overloaded. I once tried to do stuff over a mobile connection in an outdoor swimming pool which went great up to the first nice day when there where 500+ people.

Depending on how your system works it might be pretty easy to introduce a local concentrator between the iPads and the server which can preload the questions, cache the results and batch the votes. That would greatly reduce the number of outgoing connections and the bandwidth required.